# Vim に導入したプラグインが有効にならない

Tags: vim

Vimを使用してみようと思い、便利そうなプラグインを導入しようと試みたのですが

```
:help
```

でLOCAL ADDITIONSを見ても一部しか導入されていない状況です。
導入方法に何か問題があるでしょうか。以下は.vimrcファイルのプラグイン部分です。
この状態では、surroundとfzfが入ってない状態になってしまいました。

github:
surround
https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

fzf
https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim

```
"------------------------------------------------
" Plugin設定
"------------------------------------------------
" vundle.vimを使う                                                                   
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" golang用
Plugin 'fatih/vim-go'
Plugin 'nsf/gocode', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
let g:go_fmt_command = "goimports"
let g:go_auto_sameids = 1

" Markdown用
Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'
let g:vim_markdown_folding_style_pythonic = 1
" TableFormatはよく使うのでエイリアス
:command TF TableFormat
" list追加時のindentは行わない
let g:vim_markdown_new_list_item_indent = 0

" Ctrl+P
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'

" NERDTree netrwでシンボリックリンク辿れないので仕方なく
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
" Ctrl-eで NERDTreeToggle
nnoremap <silent><C-e> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" dbext                                                                              
Plugin 'vim-scripts/dbext.vim'
" ヒストリファイルはドットファイルに
let  g:dbext_default_history_file = '~/.dbext_history'
" プロファイルを記述したファイルがあれば読み込む
if filereadable(expand('~/.dbext_profile'))
source ~/.dbext_profile
endif

" snippet
Plugin 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim'
if !has('nvim')
  Plugin 'roxma/nvim-yarp'
  Plugin 'roxma/vim-hug-neovim-rpc'
endif

Plugin 'Shougo/neosnippet.vim'
Plugin 'Shougo/neosnippet-snippets'

let g:neocomplcache_snippets_dir = "~/.vim/snippets"

" surround
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'

" fzf
Plugin 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }
Plugin 'junegunn/fzf.vim'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
"------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:helptags ALL`を試してみてください。改善するかもしれません。

手元の環境では

- vim-surroundは導入すれば`:help`に以下の行が追加されました。

> surround.txt  Plugin for deleting, changing, and adding "surroundings"

- `fzf`に関しては何らかの理由で`:help`の目次に登録されないようです。

`:FZF`が使えるならプラグインの導入そのものは成功しています。
`:help fzf`でヘルプが表示されるなら同梱されているヘルプの参照もできています。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。解決しました。
結論としてはPluginではどうしてもfzf含めプラグインできない状態だったので
代わりにPlugを使用したらできるようになりました！
まだPlugでできてPluginで出来ない理由がわかっていませんがわかり次第ここでフォローしたいと思います。